# Torus in differential geometry.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, self-learning

I want to write separately parametrizations (surface patches) $\sigma$ for **torus** when (1) x-axis rotation in the first part of the picture and (2) y-axis rotation in the second part of the picture.

[image]

But I cannot. Please show me how to write?

[image]

Comment: Almost. That matrix rotates around the $x$-axis (note how it fixes points of the form $\langle \lambda, 0, 0 \rangle$.

To rotate around the $y$-axis, use $$\begin{pmatrix} \cos v & 0 & \sin v \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -\sin v & 0 & \cos v \end{pmatrix}$$.

(also, notice that your solution has $x = 0$ in it, but the torus is not flat, so you can tell something's up)

Comment: How to find this matrix: note that points like $\langle 0, \lambda, 0 \rangle$ should stay fixed. So the second row is $0, 1, 0$. Also, $p_y$ does not show up in $x$ or $z$, so the second column has $0$s in those places. At $v = 0$, we want the identity matrix, so that tells you which entries are sine and which are cosine. Trying $\langle 1,0,0 \rangle$ gives you which sine is positive and which is negative. (if you don't care about direction of rotation, pick one arbitrarily)

Comment: I am really happy thanks to you:))) I have learnt very well right now:) thanks a lot:)) @HenrySwanson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we parameterize the circle:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b + a \cos u \\ 0 \\ a \sin u \end{pmatrix}$$
Now we need to rotate this around the $z$ axis. Given an arbitrary point $p$, we can rotate it around the $z$-axis by this parameterization:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos v & -\sin v & 0 \\ \sin v & \cos v & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} p_x \\ p_y \\ p_z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} p_x \cos v - p_y \sin v \\ p_x \sin v + p_y \cos v \\ p_z \end{pmatrix} $$
If we apply this to our circle, we get:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} (b + a \cos u) \cos v - 0 \sin v \\ (b + a \cos u) \sin v + 0 \cos v \\ a \sin u \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} (b + a \cos u) \cos v \\ (b + a \cos u) \sin v \\ a \sin u \end{pmatrix}$$

Can you extend this to the second example as well?

Comment: +1 for the matrix explanation. I had never considered this way to construct such parametrizations.

Comment: In fact, I cannot understand torus enough. First of all,  is what you write for z-axis rotation i.e the first one example?

Comment: Well, now, can I find the second example? And then can you check it?

Comment: Yes, what I wrote is for the first example (rotating around the $z$-axis). And sure, I can check it.

Comment: But I dont understand how to write the second matrix:(

Comment: You know it will fix the $y$ coordinate, and that the $y$ coordinate plays no role in what happens to $x$ and $z$. This should tell you the second row and second column of the matrix. Somehow cosines and sines fill the last four entries, test points such as $1,0,0$ to confirm which go where.

Comment: Dear H.Swanson I did the second example. And I posted it as a picture. Sorry I don't know matrix writing in MathJax. Hopefully this is readable. Please check it:) thanks a lot:)